# Compare 2 arrays and show unmatched elements from array 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have 2 arrays as follows. I want to compare both arrays and only provide the elements from 'check' which are not present in 'data' array.

```
var check= ["044", "451"],
data = ["343", "333", "044", "123", "444", "555"];
```

The function used is as follows. This function will result in providing the elements in 'check' array which are present in 'data' array

```
function getMatch(a, b) {
var matches = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var e = 0; e < b.length; e++ ) {
        if ( a[i] === b[e] ) matches.push( a[i] );
    }
}
return matches;
}

getMatch(check, data); // ["044"] ---> this will be the answer as '044' is only present in 'data'
```

I want to have a list of elements which are not present in 'data' array. Can someone let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1187518/215552) seems pretty close to what you're looking for...,

Comment: `var notPresent = check.filter(function(item) { return data.indexOf(item) < 0; });`

Comment: also - the code above is more simply `function getMatch(a, b) { return a.filter(function(item) { return b.indexOf(item) >= 0; });}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `filter` and `Set`, providing the `Set` as context to the `filter` method, so it can be accessed as `this`:

```js
var check= ["044", "451"],
data = ["343", "333", "044", "123", "444", "555"];

var res = check.filter( function(n) { return !this.has(n) }, new Set(data) );

console.log(res);
```

Note that this runs in *O(n)* time, contrary to `indexOf`/`includes` based solutions, which really represent a nested loop.

Comment: this solution is helpful but what if i've array of objects to compare? can you provide solution for this scenario?

Comment: Sure, that is possible. Have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47042484/5459839).

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of ways to achieve this, however I will keep your style of coding. Before nested loop set matches flag to false and set it to true in nested loop if match found, after nested loop check your flag if it is false then push element in missing array.

```
function getMissing(a, b) {
    var missings = [];
    var matches = false;

    for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        matches = false;
        for ( var e = 0; e < b.length; e++ ) {
            if ( a[i] === b[e] ) matches = true;
        }
        if(!matches) missings.push( a[i] );
    }
    return missings;
}
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason of downvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` and `filter` for this:

```
check.filter((item) => { 
  return data.indexOf(item) === -1 
})
```

Comment: Fair enough, here without arrow function:

    check.filter(function(item) { return data.indexOf(item) === -1 })

Here with includes:

    check.filter((item) => { return !data.includes(item) })

;-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

The `.find()` method, as mentioned in a comment, only returns a single value satisfying the predicate function it is given. To correct this, simply substitute `.find()` with the `.filter()` function and it should work as intended. Thanks for the catch.

If you're familiar with ES6, you can use the purpose-built `.find()` Array method; it is, afterall, provided for situations just like the one described. It takes a predicate function and returns the values from the array `.find()` was called on (here, `check`) that satisfy the predicate function argument. In my code, the predicate function simply checks for values that are not present in the `data` array. `.includes()` is likewise a product of the recent ES6 JavaScript specification and returns a Boolean.

```js
var check= ["044", "451"],
data = ["343", "333", "044", "123", "444", "555"];

let notPresentInData = check.filter(val => !data.includes(val));
console.log(notPresentInData);
```

Comment: *"It...returns the values*": `find` returns ***one*** value, not an array, as you can see in the snippet's output.

Comment: Nice catch. I replaced `find` with `filter`... think that solves that issue.